# Macro does not compile on Linux with gcc

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have used following macro:

```
#define chSTR2(x) #x
#define chSTR1(x) chSTR2(x)
#define TODO(x) message(__FILE__"(" chSTR1(__LINE__) ") : TODO: " #x)
#define TODOEX(msg, usr) __pragma(message(__FILE__"(" chSTR1(__LINE__) ") : TODO("#usr"): " #msg))
```

When I try to use it inside my code like this:

```
TODOEX("Implement case when knzKorrIRS=j", kun01826);
```

And I try to compile this on Linux machine with gcc compiler (version 4.7.3) I get following error:

```
some_file.cpp:152:7: error: 'message' was not declared in this scope
some_file.cpp:152:7: error: '__pragma' was not declared in this scope
```

On my Windows machine with Microsoft compiler (Visual Studio 2013) I get no errors and everything works ok.

If I use TODO in my code in the following way

```
#pragma TODO(Some text)
```

then everything is ok (also on Linux machine with gcc).

I have tried to look for an answer but did not find anything which would explain the problem in gcc. So, can please somebody explain me what did I do wrong and how can I correct this that it would compile also on my Linux machine with gcc compiler installed.

Comment: Well, `message()` and `__pragma` are obviously MSVC extensions. You'll need to find their GCC equvalents.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yep, I saw the duplicate mark  and read that __pragma is actually supported only by some of the compilers. Ok, I think this actually answers my question. I will use this stuff with #pragma it is no problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: `__pragma` is a Microsoft-specific extension. `warning`, on the other hand, is just a specific `#pragma` implementation. While Microsoft-specific as well, it's a standards compliant language construct.